# Change bash history file after login

Tags: bash

I have a server there I have a user without any root privileges and this user used by other teammates. I couldn`t change **.profile**, **.bashrc** for this user. I can source bash files from my subdirectory only. I tried to source my **.bashrc** file to create prompt I used to and export history settings

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
HISTSIZE=
HISTFILESIZE=
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
export HISTFILE=<path to my subdirectory>/.hist_bash
```

But after sourcing my .bashrc I lost any history at all.
Is it possible to change bash history file after login?

**UPD**

I want to have a separate history file, because it`s hard to find my commands, we have a big team and only one user for work

Comment: Yes, see `history` in `man bash` under the section `BASH_BUILTINS`. It lists for you the options to the `history` command to modify, delete, append, perform substitution, etc.. on your `.bash_history` file. You probably do not want to share your history file as sensitive information may be contained in it.

Answer (score 1):

> > Is it possible to change bash history file after login?

I beleive what you are trying to do is not show the commands that you are running each time you login from your machine.

Simply execute the following command on each login.

unset HISTFILE

Comment: I want to see only my commands because we have a big team and it`s annoying to search my last commands . So can I unset HISTFILE and export my HISTFILE?